# LINQ to SQL combining read uncommitted and read committed

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

I'd like to use LINQ to SQL as the data layer for an application. Optimistic concurrency seems like it would work, but I'd like to be over-optimistic and not bother with any locking (e.g. `ReadUncommitted` a.k.a. `WITH (NOLOCK)`) until I get to `SubmitChanges()`, at which point I think it's OK to use `ReadCommitted`.

Does this sound like madness? Is it better to use two disjunct `TransactionScope` objects (one for reading with `ReadUncommitted`, followed by a second for submitting changes with `ReadCommitted`), or is there some nicer way I can raise the isolation level immediately before submitting changes?

Comment: If you are reading why would you do it in a transaction scope at all.  Transactional selects are meaningless.

Comment: This is not true. By reading uncommitted data, it is possible that data was later rolled back and thus the user is updating a ghost. And by not keeping a read lock on the data, it is possible for another user to update the data which this update will blindly overwrite.

Comment: I beg to differ. A transactional read with the readuncommitted option will allow me immediate (faster) access to rows that may be locked by other processes.

Comment: @DevDelivery - I am not aware of a situation where (with LINQ to SQL's built-in optimistic concurrency checks) a process could blindly overwrite another's data. I see it as a first-update-wins scenario, where later update attempts fail with ChangeConflictExceptions. And If one process *was* updating a ghost, it would still require the ghost's lock to be released before saving the update...

Comment: @Jono - I was pointing out that transactional selects have value. Yes, the concurrency check can avoid this but you have to set it all up - specify which columns to check for conconcurrency then catch any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadCommitted` or `ReadUncommitted` does not matter on a `SubmitChanges()` because it is a write, not a read. No matter what the isolation level, an update always acquires a lock and respects existing locks. It has to, that is the main purpose of locks.

Of course, by updating uncommitted data you run the risk that the record does not even still exist to be updated, but that was the risk you accepted when deciding to be optimistic.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. LINQ to SQL needs to check on the ROWVERSION field to check for optimistic concurrency conflicts before it commits the changes. My concern was that it might continue using my transaction's isolation level of ReadUncommitted in the concurrency check.

Comment: Transaction isolation level is unrelated to the concurrency check.

Comment: I guess you are thinking that the concurrency check first does a read to check concurrency and, if it is ok, does the update. However, the concurrency check is built into the update statement itself and as I pointed out in the answer, Update always respects locks.

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what happened. I guess I could look at the Log output to verify that it's just a solitary update, which - you are correct in pointing out - always takes out locks. If this is the case, then I can get by with a single TransactionScope for building up the entities in the context...

Comment: thanks, it looks like you're right. The UPDATE statement itself is the concurrency check: it uses the ROWVERSION field in the WHERE clause.